# how to divide exponential values in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, exponential, pow

I want to divide the exponential values by 1000 in Javascript. For now I am using this calculation:

```
1.02e+30 / Math.pow(10, 3)
```

In this case I am getting result as `1.0200000000000001e+27`, but if I divide `1.03e+30 / Math.pow(10, 3)` this value I am getting `1.03e+27` like this. Can anyone please explain why I am getting like this.

```
1.02e+30 / Math.pow(10, 3) ==\> 1.0200000000000001e+27

1.03e+30 / Math.pow(10, 3) == \> 1.03e+27
```